# What is the best/easiest way to set up login/ registration screen within iOS app, with Facebook, Gmail & other registration links

Tags: ios, authentication, xcode7, facebook-login, swift4

What is the best/easiest way to set up login/ registration screen within iOS app, with Facebook, Gmail & other registration links.

Comment: Have you done any research into the topic?

Comment: Yes. I have gone through tutorials for Facebook login & google login and also for user registration through Firebase authorisation. Wanted to get a sense of what is the latest best practice and what professionals are using at the moment for easy set up. I am only at beginner stage. There are lot of tutorials out there... my question here is to cut through the clutter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pod 'GoogleSignIn' for Google sign in it provides you with a button you can use and everything you need to make it work.

Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

As for the others I don't know.

Comment: Thanks! What do u use for other login setups?

Comment: I haven't used any others yet but I will be in the near future.